# Determining equilibrium solutions for non-linear first order ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the first order ODE:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2-r\sqrt{x}, ~~ x\geqslant 0
$$

How do I determine the possible equilibrium solutions? The answer is $y=0$ but I am unsure as to how one arrives at that.

Comment: Are you sure that the given answer and the equation belong together? One could argue that certain solutions converge asymptotically towards $y=-\sqrt{r\sqrt x}$, but $y=0$ is never a stationary point.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. If it helps, the previous question asks us to find the value(s) of $r$ such that at least one equilibrium solution exists. The answer is $r=0$

Comment: This is an important information, for that specific value of $r$ you get indeed that $y^2=0$ has the only solution $y=0$. For general $r$ the right side does not have roots that are independent of $x$.

Comment: I guess I’m actually not understanding how to get $r$, I thought it would’ve been $r=\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: But you want $r$ to be a constant, and the stationary point $y_*$ to be a constant, while $x$ is variable...

Comment: An equilibrium solution is when $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ and it will equal 0 whenever $r=\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{x}}$, correct? Why does $r$ have to be constant? Thanks heaps for the help

Comment: @HarryStuart From the question, it seems that $r$ is parameter of the system and hence a _constant_, so it is not possible for it to be equal to something that is _not_ constant. If $r$ is a function of $x$, you should state that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

At each instant in time, a solution is growing if $y>\sqrt{r}\sqrt[4]x$ or $y<-\sqrt{r}\sqrt[4]x$ and falling in the interval in the middle. From these qualitative observations alone one sees that negative solutions tend towards the curve $y=-\sqrt{r}\sqrt[4]x$, while for large positive initial values you get divergence to $+\infty$. Somewhere in the smaller positive initial values is a point that divides these two possibilities.

In no case other than $r=0$ do you get stationary solutions $y(x)=y_*$. In the case $r=0$ the condition $y'=0$ is only satisfied for $y_*=0$.

WolframAlpha can be used for phase portraits, left for some nonzero $r$, right for $r$ nearly zero (the function needs `x` to be present in a non-trivial way)

```
streamplot[{1,y^2-2 sqrt(x)}, {x,0,10}, {y,-5,5}]
streamplot[{1,y^2-0.001*sqrt(x)}, {x,0,10}, {y,-5,5}]
```

[image]
[image]